Textarea and button static inside popover-body
I want to use a Bootstrap popover on each OnHold input checkbox. The popovers display in modal-view. The code shows and hides the popover fine. However, the textarea and button within the popover are not working.
On show, I want the textarea within the popover to receive the focus. Instead, the focus is on the delete button, which is not what I want.
Static Popover
I have tried to fix the problem by setting entire popover dynamically. I have also tried popover-body html, but in both cases this problem exists.


$('[data-field="OnHold"]', row)
  .attr('id', x.Id)
  .prop('checked', x.OnHold)
  .popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'click',
    customClass: 'shadow',
    placement: 'top',
    title: 'On Hold Reason',
    sanitize: false,
    container: 'body',
    //content needs to setTimeout
    content: function() {
      return $('.popoverContent').clone().show();
    }
  })
  .on('shown.bs.popover', function(event) {
    const popover = $(this).next('.popover'); // Acessa o popover imediatamente após o elemento clicado

    // Foca na textarea dentro do popover exibido
    popover.find('textarea').trigger('focus');

    // Lida com o clique no botão dentro do popover clonado
    popover.find('button').on('click', function(e) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      const reason = popover.find('textarea').val(); // Pega o valor da textarea dentro do popover
      alert('Button clicked with reason: ' + reason);
    });
  })
  .on('change', function(e) {
    x.OnHold = $(this).prop('checked');
    console.log(`${x.Id}: OnHold changed to ${x.OnHold}`);

    $(this).attr('data-content', 'new text').data('bs.popover');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  
<div class="col-2">
  <div class="form-switch">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" data-field="OnHold" id="189710" aria-label="On Hold" data-bs-original-title="On Hold" data-content="new text" aria-describedby="popover3517">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="popover-Content" class="popoverContent" style="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="popover-textarea" rows="5" cols="40" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter reason">      
    </textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mx-auto">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- jQuery + Bootstrap 5 -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>




"The popovers display in modal-view." Here's a crazy idea, why not use the modal plugin?
